# Python Elif Flowdown Value Selector - How do I cap the values and prevent error?

Tags: python

this a project I've been working on, this is a baseline version of a stat selection system.

What I am trying to do is two things:
One: Prevent the user from inputing a value larger than 40.
Two: Prevent the user from receiving a error message when no value is received, but without looping the whole segment from the start.

If anyone can either suggest a solution to these problems or provide a new concept in alternative to what I have written, that would be great.

And if the answer is either blindingly obvious or written somewhere else I do apologize, I'm rather new to both Python and especially Stackoverflow, and I'm still grasping the correct terminology

Thanks

```
stealth = int(input("Stealth:"))
if stealth >= 40:
    print ("Points Spent!")
else:
    luck = int(input("Luck:"))
    if stealth + luck >= 40:
        print ("Points Spent!")
    else:
        perception = int(input("Perception:"))
        if stealth + luck + perception >= 40:
            print ("Points Spent!")
        else:
            swordsmanship = int(input("Swordsmanship:"))
            if stealth + luck + perception + swordsmanship >= 40:
                print ("Points Spent!")
            else:
                archery = int(input("Archery:"))
                if stealth + luck + perception + swordsmanship + archery >= 40:
                    print ("Points Spent!")
                else:
                    constitution = int(input("Constitution:"))
                    if stealth + luck + perception + swordsmanship + archery + constitution>= 40:
                        print ("Points Spent!")
                    else:
                       agility = int(input("Agility:"))
```

Comment: Why not just ask for them all up front, then sum them and check at the end if the sum is `>= 40`?

Comment: Well what I was trying to do is check each one, that way if a value is over 40, the user doesn't have to re-enter all of them again. It just loops for that one in particular.

Comment: I was thinking though, if the problem is that they entered too large of a previous value, they may want to start over/change previous values.

Comment: There wouldn't have been any way for you to know this, but I did have a system to allow the user to confirm their actions. I just wanted to put a individual failsafe in just so the program doesn't return a error if nothing is entered by accident

Comment: If you just want to guard against `''` being entered, I'd create a helper function that calls `input` for you. Have it call `input`, and loop until the user gives a non-empty string answer. Then return the valid input from the function, and use it in the code you have here where you're currently using `input`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood problem correctly , you having list of values to be shown to user, untill sum of values entered so far is >=40 . Once this is reached you will stop by printing "Points spent"

I think you can accomplish this like :

```
def get_input(msg):
  ret = None
  while True:
    val = input(msg)

    if len(val) > 0:
      ret = int(val)
      break
  return ret

    def imput_and_print(s,lst,index):
        if index < len(lst):
            #val = int(input(lst[index] + " : "))
            val = get_input(input(lst[index] + " : "))
            s += val
            if(s>= 40):
                print ("Points Spent!")
            else:
               imput_and_print(s,lst,index+1)


    tries_list = ["Stealth","Luck","Perception","Swordsmanship","Archery","Constitution","Agility"]

    imput_and_print(0,tries_list,0)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this will work. My coding skills are not as good as yours clearly, as yours is much more simple. However, when this is run the two issues I was trying to solve was receiving a error message when no value is given, but looping it back to the input. Secondly, the user can still input values over 40 if done in a single variable. Thank-you for your contribution, but unfortunately this does not solve my issue